# Is it good practice to constantly update a database in an Android app?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cloud

I'm creating an android scoreboard app where the users update their scores and can view them later along with some stats, etc. Now, every time the user interacts with the app (presses a button), the score updates.

Should I update the SQLite database with every click the user performs? (since the user can choose to exit the app at any time but when he/she comes back the scores and data should still be there) or should I update the database only when each game is over?

Obviously, the first choice makes more sense to me but what would be the best way to implement it? Also, is it good practice to constantly be updating a DB? Should I use background threads? Should I back the data to a server or keep it local (in case the app is deleted)?
(This is my first time creating an Android app and first time ever working with databases - so I don't know what the best practices are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the fact that it is not a good practice by desing to constantly update the DB (at least it does not seem reasonable to do it each time user touches the screen, intense IO and concurrency issues if you will not handle it properly), it really depends on the logic of your game. If the game logic allows I would optimise it and save the final score at the end of the game play so by exiting in the middle of the game play the user will lose his score.

Regarding the local vs remote db. I think it depends if you want global highscore table or local only for the user. It should not depend on wether the user deleted the game or not. If he did,  he will probably not care about his lost highscore.

Comment: It's not a game. It's only a scoreboard designed to keep track of real life scores for cue sports (such as snooker) and offer some additional stats and data.

So in a situation where the user while playing a game decides to do something else and then gets back to the game (he/she could've closed the app or restarted the phone or what not), i want to be able to offer the option of continuing the previously unfinished game - What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: I am confused, you say it is not a user interactive game but at the end you say "...offer the option of continuing the previously unfinished game." If you track the score of real life game (from ESPN for example - no matter how you get the score), why do you need to update DB each time user presses the screen? What exactly are you updating? The real life game score?

Comment: It's an app to keep track of your score when you're playing snooker in real life. When you pot a ball for real, you update your score on the app. It is a way of keeping track of your real life snooker match. It's not from ESPN, etc. It's your score from you playing snooker with your friends. Therefore it can exist in your phone for as long as you want with some additional info. So obviously, the user can pause his real life snooker match which he's playing with his friends to do anything he wishes. When he comes back to continue the game as he has left it, the scores should still be available.

Comment: :) Ok, now it is clear. In this case I do not see any reason why not to constantly update score in DB as it is not so rapid. In your case the DB will be updated every 10sec-1min between players turns.

Comment: Nice to know :) I will implement it. Should I just use the main thread or use asynctask, etc (no idea on any of those) to make it efficient?

Comment: Avoid from IO operations on your main thread. AsyncTask, IntentService, Thread or any other async worker.

Answer (score 1):

The Android framework will tell you when your activity is no longer active (`onPause`) or visible (`onStop`). This would be the correct time to safe any changes.